# Select certain value from API return

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to select a certain part of the return string to use as the isEqual.

```
guest_user_id = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithData:[APIv2 Guest_Sign_Up:guest_email] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
guest_user = [guest_user_id JSONValue];
appDelegate.guest_user_id = guest_user [@"id"];

    NSData *jsonData = [guest_user_id dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *e;
NSMutableDictionary *jsonList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
NSLog(@"jsonList: %@", jsonList[@"success"]);

if([jsonList [@"success"] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
```

The return from the API looks like this...

```
Return: {"success":0,"error":"That email address is already registered! Please try again or login."}
```

It won't see that it is false and just goes to the else. Any ideas?! :)

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to turn the JSON blob you get back from the web into a ObjectiveC objects using NSJSONSerialization, then ask the returned object for the value for "success".

So now you have use the serializer, and you get ObjectiveC objects back:

id foo = NSJSONSerialization(.....);

So what do you do now? Well you can use NSLog to dump the output and see what it looks like. That call uses symbols that let you see when something is a dictionary, string, etc.

Sometimes its hard to figure out what something is - for instance "0". Is that a number or a string. So the way to deal with this special case can be done in a simple fashion:

NSInteger theNum = [[val objectForKey:@"Success"] integerValue], since both NSString and NSNumber implement that method (I use this extensively in my code).

But, you really want to know what the object is - just to know. So what yo do then is get the object:

id foo = [val objectForKey:@"Success"];
NSLog(@"Success is a %@", NSStringFromClass([id class]);

You want to deal with this in code, then:

if([foo isKindOfClass[NSNumber class]) {
    ...
} else if([foo isKindOfClass:[NSString class])) {
    ...
}

Comment: Sorry...I am a bit of a noob, but what would that look like?

Comment: Well, time to become less of a noob. What all us old timers do is read read read the Class descriptions and guides - over and over and over again. The ability to read these descriptions and then write code that uses them is what it takes to be successful in this field. Did you look at NSJSONSerialization? You can read the description, and I'm 100% sure their are tens if not hundreds of postings on it on this site. It takes a JSON string (which is that string you have) and turns it into ObjectiveC objects, NSDictionaries, NSNumbers, NSStrings, and NSArrays.

Comment: Hey @david-h. I went through all the documentation and updated the original question. It is still getting an error though when it hits, if([jsonList [@"success"] isEqualToString:@"0"]){

Comment: So, NSLog() is your friend here. Log the return from NSJSONSerialization and see what the object is for @"success". Post that along with the code that calls the serialization and processes the return if all else fails.

Comment: The object for success is 0. Basically if it fails, it is 0 and if it is successful it is 1. The return is coming in correct in NSLog, but just when actually having it use that value in the if statement, that is what is not working..I just don't know if the equalToString is correct.

Comment: It may be returning an NSNumber. I suggest you take the integerValue of the object (which works for NSStrings and NSNumbers both), and compare the result to 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks again David. So I set it up like this: NSNumber *error_code;
    error_code = jsonList[@"success"]; and have the if statement like this: if([error_code isEqualToNumber:0]){ I think that was what you were saying and that seems like it would work to me, it throws a "NSInvalidArgumentException"??